# How can I restore an iCloud backup to a new device?

Tags: ios, icloud, restore

I have a new iPad And am trying to restore it from the back up of my old iPad. iCloud storage shows 3 backups - my iPhone, my old iPad and the new iPad (empty).

How do I get the old iPad backup on to my new iPad?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution myself in the meantime.

Seems new ipad was using an older iOS than the old one was when i backed it up, which is why it couldn't find the iCloud backup and forced me to set it up as a new ipad and use iTunes. It is all better now!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you set up the new iPad as a "new iPad". In order to restore to the old backup, you will need to reset the device.

1. Open the Settings app, tap "General", and scroll down to "Reset"
2. After tapping Reset, tap "Erase all Content and Settings"
3. Follow the prompts to wipe the device
4. After the device is wiped you will be guided through several screens guiding you in setting the iPad
5. Tap "Restore from iCloud" when prompted
6. Select your old iPad backup from all of the backups you have listed (if you are restoring across model lines - say iPod to iPad, those backups will be listed below the iPad backups, but on the same screen as the rest of the backups)
7. Let it restore your backup
8. Celebrate

Scroll towards the bottom of [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859) for additional information on restoring your device. You sometimes need to update the OS on the device if a backup was made from a newer OS than you have running on the device doing the restore.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the first few screens, one is the restore or new iPad screen. There you select restore from iCloud backup. If you go past this screen you will need to reset the device from the settings.

Answer (score -3):

HI go to recycle bin and click yourself.